# jquery get list of input values after blur one

Tags: input, this, blur, val

I have a plugin translate page:
In this page I insert a row of flags and a form with original text of post and inputs for translation.
At the end of form there is the submit button.

I want to activate/deactivate automatically the submit button when conditions are met:

- When I leave one input (jQuery "blur"): check if this one and all other inputs are empty or not.

If I use .each() function followed by $(this) I get all values of form but if $(this) object is called after $(this).on('blur',...) it is no longer focuses on inputs form.

How can I get a list of inputs value after leaving one of them ?

```
$('form input').each(function(){
var eachinput = $(this);
// Well return list of form inputs ->
console.log('name='+ $(this).attr('name')+ ' value='+ $(this).val());
 
   $(this).on('blur',function(){

      //Return the last input filled instead of all form inputs ->
      console.log('name='+ eachinput.attr('name')+ '  value='+ eachinput.val());
      
      if($('input').val().length == 0){ // If All empty (and flag not selected)
         $('#translation_button').prop( "disabled", true );
      }else{ // If one of input filled (and flag is selected)
         $('#translation_button').prop( "disabled", false );
      }
   });
});
```

I have tried .get(), but it doesn't work with .val() and .attr().